# How to add cover-art to mp3 file using Mp3tag program

Tags: mp3

Ok, I've downloaded the GUI-pgm "Mp3tag" v3.11 (onto Win-10).

I have a directory containing a bunch of MP3 files (which I extracted ('ripped') from CDs using a Windows-builtin pgm
"Windows Media Player" (aka "WMP")

The single task I now want to perform is to locate cover-art for each MP3 file and embed it into that MP3 file.

I found some 'help' info for using Mp3tag, but I can't make any sense out of it. It is here: https://aboutdevice.com/how-to-add-cover-art-to-audio-using-mp3tag/

[ If there is an easier to use free pgm, instead of Mp3tag
please recommend it.]

Answer (score 1):

[@user2112949](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2112949/david-cook)
it's very simple. in the left  frame that you change tags and others, right click on cover then click on add cover. you can remove other cover with the same way.[mp3tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNfJx.png)

Comment: Many thanks, Reza ! You're right...it IS that simple.  (I guess maybe it's me who is so simple.)

Answer (score 0):

To add a cover to one (or more) selected file(s) in Mp3tag, you can just drag & drop an existing cover art (from a local path or an online source) to the so called "tag panel" on the left side. Drop the cover to the "CD" picture landing zone on the lower left side and don't forget to save this change into the file(s) with CTRL+S or a click on the blue floppy disc icon in the toolbar.